# How to know if a form is Reactive form or Template Driven Form

Tags: angular

I have joined a new project and got the code to local. I just started using Angular.

The application is using Angular version 6. I am not sure which type forms are being used.

Is there any way I can find out?

In the following the examples, I thought 1st example was using Reactive forms because of "FormGroup" (Please correct me if I am wrong), and I am not sure about 2nd example.

Html File 1:

```html
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="Login(loginForm.value)" name="login-form" class="form">
    <div></div>
</form>
```

ts file 1:

```js
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


public ngOnInit() {
this.getInitData();
this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'username': [null, Validators.required],
  'password': [null, Validators.required],
  'rememberMe': false
});
```

Html File 2:

```html
<form id="aForm" target="_blank" action="{{Url}}" method="post" #aForm>
   <input type="submit" (click)="aForm.submit()" value="submit" /> 
</form>
```

ts file 2:

Not mentioned anything about forms.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/forms#template-driven-forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template driven Forms are in the Template, and Reactive Forms use the classes from Reactive Forms, that's the `AbstractControl` group.

A good way to look at it is:
If you see `[(ngModel)]` in the Template, it's template driven. If you see formControls formGroups and formArrays, it is reactive.

In your case, the use of `formBuilder` means it is reactive

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I added 2 examples, in 2nd one there is no ngmodel or formgroup, what category it come under?

Comment: in your second example the form is being given a variable value #aForm directly in the HTML and then accessed with 'aForm.value', that's templateDriven but really simple. If you need more logic in it then you have to mutate it into a ReactiveForm, by creating its formControl in the component and then binding it